# What it means to "drain a queue"?

Tags: queue

What it means to "drain a queue"?. Lots of people talk about "draining" the queues of the application, and I do not understand what they are talking about, to the point that I do not even know what to google (I google "What it means to "drain a queue"? " and I did not found any article  who clarify for me the concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine pulling out the plug in a sink full of water: you drain the sink until it contains no more water.

Draining a queue is about popping elements from the queue until it is empty.

In fact, "sink" is a term often used to describe things that pop elements from a queue.  Usually these elements are processed in some way.  But they may be discarded too.  It depends on the purpose.

For example: I might drain a queue of log entries to write all pending entries to the log file.  Or, I might drain a queue of user interactions (and discard them) if the program is shutting down and destroying the queue.

Answer (score 1):

The drainTo(Collection c) method removes all available elements from a queue and adds them to the given collection.